# Mapping result of Hibernate query to object

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, mapping

I have two classes:

```
public class User {
    String name;
    String surname;
}

public class ValueDto {
    User user;
    Integer value;
}
```

My query code:

```
String queryText = "SELECT DISTINCT a.* AS user, b.value AS value FROM TABLE_A a, TABLE_B b";
SQLQuery sqlQuery = aSession.createSQLQuery( queryTxt );
sqlQuery.addScalar( "value", IntegerType.INSTANCE );
sqlQuery.setResultTransformer( Transformers.aliasToBean( ValueDto.class ) );
return sqlQuery.list();
```

The problem is to get a.* AS user, where user is another class. I tried addEntity method, addScalar and maybe something else that I don't remember, also tried to find solution in Internet but with no success. I completly don't know how to make it work. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use constructor queries with a projection query like yours, to map directly to your result objects:

```
List<MyClass> dtos = session.createQuery("SELECT NEW com.example.MyClass( e.name, e.data) FROM Entity e").list();
```

`MyClass` can be a POJO. It needs to have a public constructor with the appropriate parameters. This means that you probably will not be able to use `SELECT a.*`, but will have to use explicit column names, like `a.name`

EDIT: Having a 20-parameter constructor is definitely ugly, using a `Transformer` is a viable option, especially for working with native SQL, since it does not support the `NEW` operator.

Comment: OK, but the trick is that I can't use createQuery method, I have to use plain SQL, so I guess the only option is createSQLQuery method. The other case is that in my "a" table there is about 20 columns, so creating POJO with 20 fields and then passing it all into query constructor seems really annoying.

Comment: Using  Hibernate Transformers is probably the best option you can use with native SQL.

Comment: That's right. But by transformers I have list all the fields for DTO. I want to return one object that contains other object and some other fields.

Comment: If you can only use native SQL, your options for getting the right type with the right values are very limited. If neither HQL/JPQL nor transformers are an option, you're basically out of luck and will have to iterate the resulting objects packing them as you like. Sorry, and good luck.